# How can I find the dimensions of a font drawn on a Graphics object in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, fonts

I have a Font and a FontMetrics object in my code and I'm drawing a Font onto a Graphics object but I'm not for sure how to find out the dimensions of the font when it's drawn (in pixels). Does anyone know how I could calculate that?

Answer (score 1):

The FontMetrics object you have should be all you need.  [getHeight()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getHeight()) will give you the height of the text for the font size used to create the FontMetrics object, and [stringWidth(String)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth(java.lang.String)) will tell you the width of any text that you're trying to render.

Note that you probably want to include [getAscent()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getAscent()) and [getDescent()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#getDescent()) with the height to get a full picture of what the height of the text will be.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to access [FontMetrics](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) is to get it from the graphics context after invoking `setFont()`, as seen in this [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything/2124507#2124507).