# How do I fade an image in swing?

Tags: java, swing, animation, fade

I've got class which inherits from JPanel with an image on it and i want to set up a little animation to display the panel/image and then fade it out when an event fires.

I presumably set up a thread and fire off the animation but how do I do actually do the fade?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the threading yourself, but it might be easier to use the [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) library to handle it. If you create a setter on your class called (say, `setOpacity`), you can ask trident to interpolate the "opacity" field from 1.0 to 0.0 over a specific period of time (here's [some of the docs](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/TimelineInterpolatingFields) on how to use Trident).

When you're painting the image, you can do the transparency with an `AlphaComposite`, using the updated "opacity" value for the composite's alpha parameter. There is a Sun tutorial that includes an [alpha composite example](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/swing2d).

Comment: @Ash: +1, I was going to suggest using AlphaComposite.

Comment: Does Trident do 'easing' of interpolation as well?

Comment: I believe it does linear interpolation (mostly?), based on this blog post by Trident's author (second to last paragraph): http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1599

Comment: and I believe such an opacity will not works on the fading out the jlabel's image, tough.
it will give an exception...yeah, JLabelFader exception.

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example using alpha transparency. You can use [this composite tool](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) to see the result of using different colors, modes and alphas.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AlphaTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final Font FONT = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 32);
    private static final String STRING = "Mothra alert!";
    private static final float DELTA = -0.1f;
    private static final Timer timer = new Timer(100, null);
    private float alpha = 1f;

    AlphaTest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(256, 96));
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer.addActionListener(this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setFont(FONT);
        int xx = this.getWidth();
        int yy = this.getHeight();
        int w2 = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(STRING) / 2;
        int h2 = g.getFontMetrics().getDescent();
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, xx, yy);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2d.drawString(STRING, xx / 2 - w2, yy / 2 + h2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        alpha += DELTA;
        if (alpha < 0) {
            alpha = 1;
            timer.restart();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new AlphaTest());
                f.add(new AlphaTest());
                f.add(new AlphaTest());
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For comparison, see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything/2124507#2124507) that varies the background color's saturation.

Answer (score 6):

There is some useful information describing image transparency [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/2d/spec/j2d-awt.html#wp64995).

Your approach would be something like this:

- Define a Swing [`Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to fire an `ActionEvent` on the Event Dispatch thread every N milliseconds.
- Add an `ActionListener` to the `Timer` which should call `repaint()` on your `Component` containing the `Image`.
- Override the `Component`'s `paintComponent(Graphics)` method to do the following:

  - Cast the `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2D`.
  - Set an `AlphaComposite` on the `Graphics2D` using `setComposite`.  This controls the level of transparency.
  - Draw the image.

For each iteration of your fade-out animation you would change the values of the `AlphaComposite` to make the image more transparent.

Comment: My component is a child component, when I used paintComponent, it painted the whole parent inside the JPanel, overriding paint(Graphics g) instead fixed that. Is that correct?