# Jlabel with alpha value

Tags: swing, alpha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fade an image in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228735/how-do-i-fade-an-image-in-swing)

i have jLabel and i want to change its opacity (alpha value) each one second , i tried something like that but its not change each one second , JLabel change its opacity only with last alpha value .

```
  Color color = jLabel1.getBackground();
    int alpha = 255;
    long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - initTime >= 1000){
        initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        alpha -=1;
        Color color2 = new Color(color.getRed(),color.getGreen(),color.getBlue(),alpha);
        jLabel1.setBackground(color2);

        }
        if(alpha<=0)
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this on the Event Dispatch Thread, using say `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` then the repaint will only happen after your code has finished executing. For repeated updates, use the Swing Timer, as detailed in this sun tutorial:

- [How to use Swing Timers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

You might also look into the [Trident](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1090) animation library for Swing.

Comment: +1 Here's a related example that uses `javax.swing.Timer` to ensure EDT execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228735/how-do-i-fade-an-image-in-swing/2234020#2234020