# Fading Indicator message in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, swt, toast

How to/What is a good library, to create a fading indicator message in Java like that of Outlook when you get a message, or Ubuntu/Gnome when you've connected to a network?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234020

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 1.6 has a TrayIcon class that can be used to display notification messages.

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tray.gif");
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");
tray.add(trayIcon);
trayIcon.displayMessage("Hello, World", "notification demo", MessageType.INFO);
```

Here's the result:
[image: TrayIcon on Windows]
[image: TrayIcon on Linux]

On Linux you may also have a little program called notify-send. It makes it easy to invokes the standard freedesktop.org notification system from the shell. You can also run it from Java.

```
String[] notifyCmd = {"notify-send", "Hello, World!"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(notifyCmd);
```

I had to `apt-get install libnotify-bin` to get this on my Ubuntu box.

[image: notify-send]

---

I've tested these things on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10. In each case the notification disappeared after some time which is I suppose the *fading indicator* effect that you want.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Trident animation library](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home). Your task would be almost trivial if you use it.

Also you could take a look at [Timing Framework](https://timingframework.dev.java.net/), but it wasn't updated for a long time.