# Jlabel with Image Fade Out Strange Effect

Tags: java, image, animation, jlabel, fadeout

Hope this question could emphasize more about the fading out effect of Jlabel (swing).

Certainly, yes... I already follow some guide and some answers given from [This Link Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270997/making-a-jlabel-fade-away), but mine is quite a bit different. It's not just only A text inside the JLabel, there's an image i put on.

I proceed to follow on the [Thread Located out of stackoverflow](http://fr.w3support.net/index.php?db=so&id=1531494). And yet, it gives me a fade out effect. But there's horrible thing occured; **the white background.**

**How to solve this out?**

I share the interface here...
The [First screenshot taken here](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5964/jlabelfadingout.jpg) is the earlier phase when the fade out have not occured yet. While,
The [Second screenshot taken here](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/5761/jlabelfadingout2.jpg) is the unwanted result i mentioned.

Tobe honest, I used the **Trident Library** to do animatiing;
So, whenever the user click over the image it will execute this code;

```
Timeline tm = new Timeline(jll_btnProceed);
tm.addPropertyToInterpolate("intensity", 1.0f, 0.0f);
tm.setDuration(1000);
tm.play();
```

and... the JLabel itself, I used to override it using this source code;

```
/**
 *
 * @author Gumuruh
 */

public class JLabelFader extends JLabel {

    private float intensity = 1.0f;

    public void setIntensity(float intensity) {
        this.intensity = intensity;
        this.setOpaque(false);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        final Composite oldComposite = g2.getComposite();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
        final Color c = getBackground();
        final Color color = new Color(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), (int) (255 * (1.0f - intensity)));
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.setComposite(oldComposite);
    }
}
```

My hand and my head can't stop for making this trully solved. Thus I tried to follow up some example from the **Java Filthy Rich Client ebook** and then applying the source code given below, but first I need to COMMENT the **protected void paint(Graphic g)** method written above, and simply adding this source code;

```
private BufferedImage buttonImage = null;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        // Create an image for the button graphics if necessary
        if (buttonImage == null || buttonImage.getWidth() != getWidth()
                || buttonImage.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            buttonImage = getGraphicsConfiguration().
                    createCompatibleImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        Graphics gButton = buttonImage.getGraphics();
        gButton.setClip(g.getClip());

        //  Have the superclass render the button for us
        super.paint(gButton);

        // Make the graphics object sent to this paint() method translucent
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        AlphaComposite newComposite =
                AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, intensity);
        g2d.setComposite(newComposite);

        // Copy the button's image to the destination graphics, translucently
        g2d.drawImage(buttonImage, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

in which at the end... giving me nice fade out effect. But At first, it gave me the **2nd horrible effect** which is **BLACK BACKGROUND** rendered first. Can't believe me?? Okay, Here is [First screen shot AFTER applying code from ebook](http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/5951/jlabelfadingoutaftertak.jpg). and here is [the nice fade out effect result](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/5951/jlabelfadingoutaftertak.jpg).

If there's somebody telling me; 
"**YOUR PNG IS NOT TRANSPARENT**!".
Please, dont say like that. Because, I followed the [creation of PNG inside the Photoshop nicely using this Tut](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-misc001.html).

Now, My head's spinned, but my heart laughed and can't handle it over. OMG. Geeezzz....!

And the New Stories begun...
*** UPDATED FROM HERE AND BELOW ***

Ehm, depply thank you very much to our friend called... **MKorbel,**
from [his thread given at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992154/java-transparent-panels-custom-effect-on-panels/6992259#6992259). Providing a clear example of fading out effect the Swing JButton and I tried to implement it into my JLabel, and violaaa...!! 
IT works. 
Let's give a big clap for **MKorbel**. :D

SO anyway, how could I fix the earlier code? Pretty simple, just **COMMENT the Paint()** method, and **use again the paintComponent() method** and it should be **overriden** with the new source code below;

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, intensity));
        if (rectangularLAF && isBackgroundSet()) {
            Color c = getBackground();
            g2.setColor(c);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        super.paintComponent(g2);
        g2.dispose();
    }
```

Now the JLabel become easy to be changed with its **intensity -variable**.
Fading out and Fading in is accomplished.

Okay. **Now everything** seems "**OKAY**". BUt hold a moment, there's something strangely occured again here. Have you noticed it? Hmmm....
I tried to give a **Mouse Event (Hover On)** into the **JLabel** that we override the **paintComponent()** method discussed earlier.With this line of code;

```
myJLabel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

Logically, it should change the Cursor when Hover ON. But, Here comes **another strange effect**. (Really sorry, but this is stil the continue of the main case). The strange effect now is the **Mouse Cursor can't be changed** when we Hover On the Jlabel. It still can't change the Cursor. **Seems the paintComponent() method effecting** the way Cursor react. Is that true?

Comment: queston -> what were happends if you tried to set/change Alpha translucency or transparency without Substance/Trident libraries

Comment: change the alpha translucency, mKorbel? which one? 
I'm actually changing the color via "intensity" variable ---> intended to give an alpha color.

Comment: please check my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992154/java-transparent-panels-custom-effect-on-panels/6992259#6992259 , only if that will be works as you expected then you can apply Trident libs.

Comment: hey, mKorbel...! 
I just realized it today, since it's OKay. and you saved my upper topics. There's still something unwanted effect. 
The Cursor seems can't be applied any longer if I tried to implement your code (paintComponents) algorithm... :(

Comment: that was very academic tread, now you are two options, edit this thread or start a new, but with runnable code that shows what you are tried ....

Comment: ya MKorbel... the thread is now updated. It is very strange... previously the fade out effect, now the cursor... OMG. Hopefully there's somebody could give us a hint about this. :)

Comment: not clear for me :-), problem is with JLabel&Cursor if mouse hover-over JLabel, or you can't ba able to change Cursor, look for MouseMotionListener + get Rectangle from JLabel on the screen :-)

Comment: @mKorbel : ya The Cursor can't be changed. I already give the mouse event on Hover and put the code, but seems it failed. But If i use the common JLabel, and not the Above-Fader-JLabel, everything works fine. :(

Comment: `Cursor` works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678

Comment: mKorbel, thanks for the posted thread. But, it doesn't effecting the JLabel above.Anyway, I already update my JDK but seems still have the problem... hmmmm.... I wonder why.

Comment: to try based you code on official tutorial and rest on http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=transparent

Comment: @mKorbel: okay, okay.... right away to go there.... :D