# Is This Bad Programming Practice

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Please consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JTree jTree;
    //Code ommited for clarity

    public void methodCalledByAnotherThread(){

       final DefaultTreeModel t = new DefaultTreeModel();
       //Do some thing with t

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void Run(){
               jTree.setModel(t);
            }
       });
   }
}
```

`MyClass` is created and executed on the Swing thread. Some time during its execution it starts a second thread which will eventually call the `methodCalledByAnotherThread()`. Not this method will NEVER be called on the Swing thread.

`methodCalledByAnotherThread()` creates a (local) `DefaultTreeModel` object and does some work with it but because this is NOT on the Swing thread it cannot set the model into `jTree` hence the call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. In the Runnable object , which is executed on the Swing thread, it sets the LOCAL `DefaultTreeModel` t into the `JTree`.

My question is (and I haven't actually compiled and run this code yet so it may not work).. is the above BAD programming practice? If so how can I set a `TreeModel` created on a NON-Swing thread into a Swing object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks fine (in fact its the best way to do it). So long as `//Do some thing with t` does not include any elements that are already displayed on the UI.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. Would you have any references saying that this is a correct way to proceed?

Comment: I found that in this question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895481/update-jlabel-from-another-thread

Answer (score 3):

1) don't `extends javax.swing.JFrame` more in [Composition versus Inheritance](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html), e.i.

2) better would be `getModel` from currnet `JTree` instance rathen than recreate `DefaultTreeModel` on runtime and maybe with un_know life cycle

3) correct is that you adding `model` by wrapping into `invokeLater`, sugestion easiest way is from `Runnable#Thread`, better from `SwingWorker`,

Comment: Concerning your #2 TreeModel is not thread safe to my knowledge. So, modifying the existing one it from another thread(s) should be considered a bad programming practice.

Comment: @ʘleg your `considering for bad programming practice` could be default way how to add/update DefaultXxxModel from the Background Task to ther Swing GUI

Comment: Modification of not threadsafe objects from other threads being the default way is not my problem :)

Comment: I don't think that _.`getModel` from current `JTree`_ returns an `AbstractXxxModel`...