# Java Swing: is there a standard fading rate?

Tags: java, swing, animation, fading

At the moment, I'm fading components in/out at a rate of `0.1 alpha/second`. I've read some examples online that use `0.03 alpha/second`. Is there a standard rate at which components should fade in/out? Is there a standard transition animation rate?

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2234020/230513). Are you looking for a rationale based on human factors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that such a standard exists and will ever exist for that reasons :

- It is mostly subjective
- It depends on the speed of the application. If your application is slow you would rather put a slow effect in order to comply with the rest or mask the slowness
- It depends on what's inside your components. For example it makes sense that a growl notification will fade slowly while an alert box will fade quickly once you click on "ok"
- Fading is just an effect it won't affect your user so much as long as it doesn't affect the functional experience (like for example a looong fading that avoids you to use other fonctionality while it is happening).