# How to get Java's TrayIcon message to fade out?

Tags: java, swing, system-tray, trayicon

I have a Java application that reduce into the system tray when the red cross is pressed.

Whenever this happen, I display a message to inform the user that the application is still running in the system tray.

Here's the code for that :

```
...

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
       try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
            trayIcon.displayMessage("", "The application has been reduced
                 in the system tray, to stop it, press the \"Quit\" button", 
                 TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
            setVisible(false);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            System.out.println("unable to add to tray");
        }
    }
...
```

For the moment, the message disappears if the user clicks on it.

I would like to set up a counter so the message would fade out after a couple of seconds even if nothing has been done.

Does anyone know a nice way to do it cause I can't seem to find any existing method for that.

**EDIT**

I have to correct my question, in fact, after testing it a little bit longer, it automatically fades out after, let's say, 7-8 seconds but I find it a little bit too long. Also, it only disappears if the user is executing an action (moving the mouse or typing on the keyboard)

So the new question would be : Is there a way to reduce the fade out time and change the message behaviour by configuring the Java application or is it inherent to Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the new question would be : Is there a way to reduce the fade out
>   time by configuring the Java application or is it inherent to Windows?

- [MSDN says in part How long to notify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx) - *In Windows Vista and later, notifications are displayed for a fixed duration of 9 seconds.*
- any changes is possible to maintain only on Windows size, but seems like is valid/applied for all messagess

---

- you can to create own Traslucent JDialog (Transparency could be way too) placed programatically to the left bottom, fading out will be invoked from Swing Timer

Comment: Maybe something like this [`AlphaTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2234020/230513)?

Comment: I could create a personal JDialog but the position should vary according to where the user has set his taskbar, it would be a lot of work just to change a small behaviour. I think I'll stick with the standard TrayIcon message. But still I'll mark your pots as the answer because I think it is the correct answer.

Comment: @Padrus this possition is very simple to calculating, because GraphicsEnvironment returns pixels ratio and Taskbar height too, or can be calculated from JFrame.getExtendedSize,