# How to set background color of a button in Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Below is the code which creates 9 buttons in gridlayout form on a specific pannel3. What i want is to make the background of each button black with grey text over it. 
Can anyone help please?

```
 for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
 {
     p3.add(new JButton(""+i));
 }
```

Comment: Honestly, people, use an IDE. Auto-complete is one of the best ways to learn the language library, and method names are usually pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy why was your comment necessary?

Comment: @JohnnyCoder, I guess I was frustrated and it was my way of saying rtfm. I still believe it's a good advice, though :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check out [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) documentation. Take special attention to `setBackground` and `setForeground` methods inherited from `JComponent`.

Something like:

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    JButton btn = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btn.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    p3.add(btn);
}
```

Comment: This does not work with Java 8 on the Mac. The background color is the color behind the button. The button is then drawn on top of the black background and the button is gray with gray text. (you cannot read the text). In fact, it's worse... the black background isn't drawn at all unless `setOpaque(true)` is called first.

Comment: Doesn't work with Java 8. as @Jason said. The background color is the color behing the button.

Comment: Using `setBorderPainted(false)` would solve the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 12):

Simple:

`btn.setBackground(Color.red);`

To use RGB values:

`btn[i].setBackground(Color.RGBtoHSB(int, int, int, float[]));`

Comment: I like to use btn.setBackground(New Color(int, int, int));  for RGB values

Answer (score 3):

Changing the background property might not be enough as the component won't look like a button anymore. You might need to re-implement the paint method as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7115672/1201614) to get a better result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
    p3.add(new JButton(""+i) {{
        // initialize the JButton directly
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    }});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not have to use setOpaque method to ensure that the colors show up by passing true to the method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the setBackground() method doesn't work well on some platforms (I'm using Windows 7). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/817961) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3420311/817961) helpful. However, I didn't entirely use it to solve my problem. Instead, I decided it'd be much easier and almost as aesthetic to color a panel next to the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [setBackground](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) method to set the background and [setForeground](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29) to change the colour of your text. Note however, that putting grey text over a black background might make your text a bit tough to read.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the previous solutions but still couldn't change the color. Came across another article and solved my problem. The button is made of different layers. Removing all of them helps:

```
    btn.setOpaque(true);
    btn.setContentAreaFilled(true);
    btn.setBorderPainted(false);
    btn.setFocusPainted(false);
    btn.setBackground(Color.GRAY); // for the background
    btn.setForeground(Color.white); // for the text
```