# Change JButton gradient color, but only for one button, not all

Tags: java, swing, gradient, background-color, jbutton

I want to change `JButton` gradient color, 
i found this, http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2009/01/set-jbutton-gradient-color.html, but i want to change gradient for only one button, not all button

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can override the [paintComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method of the `JButton` instance and paint its [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object with one of the following classes that implement the [Paint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html) interface:

- [GradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html).
- [LinearGradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html)
- [MultipleGradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MultipleGradientPaint.html)
- [RadialGradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RadialGradientPaint.html)

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public final class JGradientButtonDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();         
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Gradient JButton Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(JGradientButton.newInstance());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 150)); // used for demonstration
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class JGradientButton extends JButton {
        private JGradientButton() {
            super("Gradient Button");
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setFocusPainted(false); // used for demonstration
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
                    new Point(0, 0), 
                    Color.WHITE, 
                    new Point(0, getHeight()), 
                    Color.PINK.darker()));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2.dispose();

            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        public static JGradientButton newInstance() {
            return new JGradientButton();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: since should be L&F sensitive, but vey nice +1

Comment: best solution i've found on SO

Answer (score 7):

A little improvement over mre answer:

[image]

```
private static final class JGradientButton extends JButton{
    private JGradientButton(String text){
        super(text);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
                new Point(0, 0), 
                getBackground(), 
                new Point(0, getHeight()/3), 
                Color.WHITE));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()/3);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
                new Point(0, getHeight()/3), 
                Color.WHITE, 
                new Point(0, getHeight()), 
                getBackground()));
        g2.fillRect(0, getHeight()/3, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one implement this to a button that is already part of a GUI? Would I need to change the action listeners at all if I added this to the buttons? Is that possible? Or, better question; is it a reasonable question to ask in the first place?

Comment: If a GUI has already a button, there must be some code that creates that button (JButton b = new JButton("whatever") ). To replace the default button, you need to create a JGradientButton instead (JButton b =  new JGradientButton("whatever") ) and set the background color to what you like (b.setBackground(..somecolor...)) . The remaining code in the GUI that handle the button should be left unchanged

Comment: For eample in NetBeans' Gui Builder, select the button, go to the Properties tab 'Code', change 'Custom Creation Code'.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: it's not possible directly, but can be done with a workaround like in Luca's answer, however his/her answer uses the incorrect gradient steps. The correct ones are listed below.

### The way it works

In the Metal LAF there is a hardcoded exception. If the `background` property is a subclass of `UIResource`, it's ignored* and the button is instead painted with the (also hardcoded) gradient from the UI property `Button.gradient`. Otherwise, if `background` is not a `UIResource`, that background is painted as-is.

*unless the button is disabled, in which case there is no gradient and the color inside the `UIResource` is used for the background.

---

### The gradient

Following the logic of `MetalButtonUI`, I found out the used gradient it uses comes from the UI property `Button.gradient`, which contains the `ArrayList`:

```
0 = {Float} 0.3
1 = {Float} 0.0
2 = {ColorUIResource} "[221,232,243]"
3 = {ColorUIResource} "[255,255,255]"
4 = {ColorUIResource} "[184,207,229]"
```

Following the logic even further, I ended up in `MetalUtils.GradientPainter.drawVerticalGradient()`. This implementation interprets the above data as*:

- Gradient from 0% to 30%: color1 to color2
- Gradient from 30% to 60%: color2 to color1
- Gradient from 60% to 100%: color1 to color3

*assuming the second float is 0.0, otherwise more gradients are drawn.

Since this is a multi-stage gradient, it can't be done with a simple `GradientPaint` but can be done with a `LinearGradientPaint`. However the `background` property only accepts `Color`. It cannot even be spoofed/hacked because the actual value is eventually given to `Graphics.setColor()` and not `Graphics2D.setPaint()` (even though Metal is Swing-based and not AWT) **Dead End.** The only solution seems to subclass JButton altogether.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful with recreating the buttons in CSS!