# How do I change the color of a button, not just the border around it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to change both the background and foreground color of my button. I used setBackground and setForeground and setOpaque(true), and it worked for the foreground, but not for the background of the button. There is kind of like a black border around the button, but I want the button itself to be black. How do I fix it?

```
this.closeButton = new JButton ("Close");
    this.closeButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.closeButton.setForeground(Color.PINK);
    this.closeButton.setOpaque(true);
```

[image: This is what I have]

Comment: Edit your tags to specify which user-interface kit: JavaFX, Swing, SWT, Vaadin, etc.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172940/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-button-in-java-gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "border" is provided by the look and feel delegate.  You can "disable" it by calling `button.setBorderPainted`

This may or may not meet your expecations

[image: Close button]

```
JButton button = new JButton("Close");
button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
button.setForeground(Color.PINK);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setOpaque(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do: this.closeButton.setTextColor(Color.PINK);
uncomment line : this.closeButton.setForeground(Color.PINK) ;

Comment: `java.swing.JButton` does not have a `setTextColor` method, you might be thinking of JavaFX