# How to add color background in the button admin and user? I want to change into color blue

Tags: java, swing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhEyR.png)
Started from here for the code:

```
package com.nono.groupproject;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginGUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            LoginGUI loginGUI = new LoginGUI();
            loginGUI.createAndShowGUI();
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        setTitle("Login");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 20, 20));


        JLabel lblLoginAs = new JLabel("Login as:");
        lblLoginAs.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        panel.add(lblLoginAs);


        JButton btnAdmin = createLoginButton("Admin");
        panel.add(btnAdmin);


        JButton btnUser = createLoginButton("User");
        panel.add(btnUser);


        setContentPane(panel);



        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenWidth = (int) (screenSize.getWidth() * 0.4);
        int screenHeight = (int) (screenSize.getHeight() * 0.4);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));


        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
```

Can somebody help with what coding should i input there to add the color background in the button admin and user?

Also, can you check my coding to see if it's correct or not? Give me some advice and answers thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set background color of a button in Java GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172940/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-button-in-java-gui)

Comment: @kiner_shah This is not fit for Code Review. When it's unclear whether the code does what it should, it's not ready. The title reads like a feature-request, which is a no-go as well.

Comment: @Mast, yeah you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background color of a JButton, you can use [`setBackground()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) method, passing a [java.awt.Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

From the docs, for `setBackground()`:

> **Sets the background color of this component**. The background color is used only if the component is opaque, and only by subclasses of JComponent or ComponentUI implementations. Direct subclasses of JComponent must override paintComponent to honor this property.

Example:

```java
btnAdmin.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```