# setBackground doesn't work in windows 7

Tags: java, swing, background, jcombobox

I am trying to change background color of a `JComboBox` to red using `setBackground`. It works in windows XP, but it doesn't work in windows 7. I Try all the following solutions:

- [Why does setBackground to JButton does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990952/why-does-setbackground-to-jbutton-does-not-work)
- [How to set background color of a button in Java GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172940/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-button-in-java-gui)

here is my code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            JFrame hello = new JFrame("Hello World");
            JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
            combo.setBackground(Color.red);
            combo.setOpaque(true);
            hello.add(combo);
            hello.pack();
            hello.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                    ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider creating and posting your [minimal, compilable and runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the look and feel before creating the frame and combo box? In the earlier revision of the question you had it round the other way.

Comment: Yes. it's in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723115/changing-a-color-chooser-buttons-background-color-in-java and try this small app: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/

Comment: I don't see reason for this question, read JComboBox and rendereing concept in JComboBox, JList or JTable (very similair concept), logics is different for editable and no_editable JComboBox

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran your code, and it works fine on my Windows 7 system - 64 bit.
so I wonder, what might be wrong in your windows 7 system.

I would try to reinstall Java on that machine  !