# JToggleButton - How to change the color?

Tags: java, swing, background, foreground, jtogglebutton

I could to set the color of the button, but once the button is pressed its color is blue - standard. I want to be black. How do I change it?

Below is the current code:

```
    public JPanel gameBoard(){

        JPanel pBoard = new JPanel();
        pBoard.setSize(5*horizontalOptions,5*verticalOptions);
        pBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(horizontalOptions,verticalOptions));
        jb = new JToggleButton[verticalOptions*horizontalOptions];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<verticalOptions;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<horizontalOptions;j++){
                jb[k]=new JToggleButton ("", false);
                jb[k].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                jb[k].setBackground(Color.white);
                jb[k].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                jb[k].setForeground(Color.black);
                pBoard.add(jb[k]);
                k++;
            }
        }
        return pBoard;
    }

}
```

Comment: [read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434845/setting-the-default-font-of-swing-program) here about keys that UIManager sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that in `UIManager`:

```
UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: NB: not available on all L&Fs.

Comment: This will paint all the pressed toggle buttons black, not the one

Comment: Try examine [that topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808022/changing-the-background-color-of-a-selected-jtogglebutton)

Comment: @alex2410 work! :) Are you know why the setPreferredSize not working? I want the buttons to be squares...

Comment: Don't use setXXXsize(), all sizes must be done by LayoutManager