# Changing color of togglebutton in matlab depending on array output

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to change the background color of toggle buttons depending on my array output. Basically i have a loop which is filling the array.

```
 number = 20;
tic
A = [];
for i = 1 : number
    A = [i]
    pause(1)
end
```

Depending on what number i is inside the Array i want to change that background color of the toggle button in my GUI. so i tried with this:

```
function togglebutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if A == 1 
    set('BackgroundColor','red')
```

Sadly it didn't work. I would appreciate any help

Comment: The background color is not editable since that indicates whether the toggle is pressed or not. You'd likely have to resort to some java for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078722/jtogglebutton-how-to-change-the-color

Comment: Hello, in my main project the buttons get values from being toggled and also change the colors, but in the end i get an array as result which shows a way (of button numbers) and i wanted to light that up with color changes per button so it visualizes the way it goes.

Comment: As I said, it's not possible directly in MATLAB and you'll likely have to use a Java toggle button instead

Comment: maybe i misexplained something, i dont want to change the color of my togglebutton when i press any togglebutton... i want to change the togglebutton colors depending on the number inside my array

Answer (score 2):

It is going to be difficult to change the true background color of the `uicontrol` (with the `style` set to `'toggle'`) since that is regulated by the underlying java object. If you want to change that you'll likely have to resort to [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078722/jtogglebutton-how-to-change-the-color)

What you *could* do though, is rely on the fact that MATLAB's `uicontrol` [supports HTML-formatted strings](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents). So you could use HTML to make the button appear to be a different color

```
set(button, 'String', '<HTML><BODY bgcolor="red">Red Toggle');
```

[image]

Or personally, I think it looks better to simply change the foreground color

```
set(button, 'ForegroundColor', 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: i will try this in abit and give u feedback later

Comment: @spr1te How are you creating your toggle button? Please show that code

Comment: i created a static matrix of togglebuttons via guide interface and then imported all (they're all callbacks). inside these callbacks the buttons already change color if pressed once or twice.

in the end i get an answer array e.g. [1 2 3 4 5] and i want then the togglebuttons 1-5 to light up in another color (without pressing them)

that is my basic problem

Answer (score -2):

I realise this might not solve your fundamental issue, but keep the following in mind when changing properties.

*set* works with a reference to the handle graphics object as its first argument, i.e. your button.

```
set(button,'BackgroundColor','red')
```

This works for me on R2013a. However, the documentation states that you should only use it for releases before R2014b. For release R2014b and onwards, using dot notation should be the norm:

```
button = uicontrol('Style','togglebutton');
button.BackgroundColor = 'r';
```

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_BackgroundColor

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't work for toggle buttons.

Comment: `uicontrol('style', 'toggle', 'Backgroundcolor', 'red')` works for you?

Comment: There is no error, the value is just ignored on all versions I can test (2014a and later)

Comment: it gets ignored on my matlab version too (2016a)

Comment: Ah, I see. Makes sense, in that case, have you tried using dot notation to change properties like

Comment: button.BackgroundColor = 'r';
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the answer slightly.

Comment: sadly it doesnt work either for me idk why , is my if clause wrong? lol