# How do I change the color of a disabled jToggleButton?

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

I'm working on a game that disables `JToggleButton` buttons when I click on them, but I want the buttons to also change color when they're disabled. I disable a button with:

```java
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jToggleButton1.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I've tried using `jToggleButton1.setBackground(Color.RED);` before and after the `jToggleButton1.setEnabled(false);` but the button always turns gray anyway when it's disabled.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: try to look at this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808022/changing-the-background-color-of-a-selected-jtogglebutton

Comment: What's wrong with Gray? Pretty much the standard for a disabled control. Don't disable it then, In the **ActionPerformed** event: `jToggleButton1.setBackground(Color.red); jToggleButton1.setForeground(Color.white); If (jToggleButton1.getBackColor() == Color.red) { return; }`

Comment: The problem is that the standard UI of a button, provides no support for color change, when button is disabled. So it's possible, but requires deep Swing knowledge (you need to create your own implementation of ButtonUI based on your current Look-n-Feel).

Comment: jToggleButton1.addChangeListener(changeEvent -> jToggleButton1.setBackground(jTB1.isEnabled() ? ... : ...));`