# CheckBoxList in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I am designing a user interface in which I want to give users the option to select one or more Trainers for a particular Course. Is there such a thing as a `Checkboxlist` in Java? I am using Netbeans.What do you recommend as a best UI solution.

Comment: You can find the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766/how-do-i-make-a-list-with-checkboxes-in-java-swing

Comment: I suppose your UI is in Swing ?

Comment: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h46LO.jpg) If you want something like this, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848239/nimbus-l-f-setting-different-background-colors-of-a-check-boxes-in-a-checkbox).

Comment: I don't believe it is enough.I want something like a JComboBox with checkboxes beside the list items.

Comment: Yes Toilal my UI is in Swing

Comment: So what you want is merely a visual organization of the checkboxes? If thats the case then what you should do is just play around with the layout managers by adding the checkboxes to some "auto grouping" component such as a VBox in JavaFX (sorry I don't know the equivalent for Swing, never really used it for complex layouts)

Comment: No there is no pre-defined component of such name, but you can implement listCellRender interface, for more description Here's [a link](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5342)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this: http://chianti.ucsd.edu/svn/csplugins/trunk/soc/jgao/IDMapping/src/csplugins/id/mapping/ui/CheckComboBox.java

It is an extension of JComboBox.

[image]

Here is a quick example I whipped up, but you get the picture:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        Set<Object> options = new HashSet<>();
        options.add(new Option<Integer>("One", 1));
        options.add(new Option<Integer>("Two", 2));
        options.add(new Option<Integer>("Three", 3));
        options.add(new Option<Integer>("Four", 4));
        CheckComboBox c = new CheckComboBox(options);
        this.add(c);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }


    private class Option<T> implements Comparable<T> {
        private String label;
        private T value;

        public Option(String label, T value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.label;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(T o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since it uses a set, the options will get scrambled... I didn't write the component. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick responses as usual. I will be using a JTable with boolean fields instead. JTable seems to be a cleaner solution to me
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html