# sorting java combobox items

Tags: java, jcombobox

i'm trying to get the names and IDs from database and add them to combobox. i've added this checkcombobox to my project;

http://chianti.ucsd.edu/svn/csplugins/trunk/soc/jgao/IDMapping/src/csplugins/id/mapping/ui/CheckComboBox.java

by the help of this code;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097767

```
            ResultSet resultSet= "here getting the result set with query having a ORDER BY clause   

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt(1);
                String name = resultSet.getString(2);
                System.out.println(name);
                options.add(new Option<Integer>(name, id));
            }
```

system.out.println gives the output sorted by name but the items in checkcombobox are not sorted. how can i add the items sorted in combobox?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to sort items in a combox box.

First Make your `Option` sortable by either using a `Comparator` or implementing the `Comparable` interface, then

- First remove all the items.
- Sort the list
- Then add the items back from the sorted list.

  ```
  Collections.sort(options);
  comboBox.removeAllItems();
  for (Option s : options) {
      comboBox.addItem(s);
  }
  ```

---

Complete example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SortCombo {

    JComboBox comboBox;
    JButton sortButton;
    List<Option> options;

    public SortCombo() {
        options = createOptions();

        comboBox = new JComboBox(options.toArray());
        sortButton = new JButton("Sort");

        sortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Collections.sort(options);
                comboBox.removeAllItems();
                for (Option s : options) {
                    comboBox.addItem(s);
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort ComboBox");
        frame.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(sortButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public List<Option> createOptions() {
        List<Option> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Option("John", 1));
        list.add(new Option("Sean", 2));
        list.add(new Option("Jake", 3));
        list.add(new Option("Mike", 4));
        list.add(new Option("Abby", 5));
        list.add(new Option("Paul", 6));
        list.add(new Option("Daniel", 7));
        list.add(new Option("Chris", 8));
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SortCombo();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Option implements Comparable<Option> {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Option(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Option option) {
        return this.name.compareTo(option.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " {" + id + "}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use the `Set` constructor, use the `CheckComboBox(Map<Object, Boolean> mapObjSelected)` constructor.
2. Use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). The `Set` constructor creates a `LinkedHashMap` by default, which doesn't preserve order.
3. Properly implement the [`compareTo` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in the code for `Option`. You may need to add an extra field to tell the `Option`s what order they're supposed to be in.