# JButton clicking effect on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, keyboard-events

I'm writing a typing application where jbutton should react on key pressing by changing it's color, but the Mac LAF refuses to change it and i don't want use other LAFs. Is their any way to use "system clicking effect" (button becomes gray for a sec) on key pressing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) easiest and by default correct way -->

- change `Mac L&F` with one of (`todays`) custom [Look and Feels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968)

2) possible way --> required deepest knowledge of Swing, Java and LookAndFeels,

- not `MacOSX` user, don't know if you are using `SystemLookAndFeeel` or `MetalLookAndFeel`, but you could be able get and override from `MetalButtonUI/QuaquaButtonUI` extends `BasicButtonUI`, maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968) can help you

Comment: +1 Yes, this depends on the UI delegate; I've used this [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513).