# Java Change Button Background Color

Tags: java, swing, background, jbutton

I am using netbeans to create a desktop application, and I am trying to change the background color of a JButton, btn1 using the code

> btn1.setBackground(Color.Red)

But this does not work. Instead of changing the fill color of the button, only the border color is changed. How can I change the background fill?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420311/java-swing-button-colors/3420431#3420431) related question and answer.

> In particular, you can use setForeground() to change the color of a button's text, but the corresponding setBackground() doesn't read well on some platforms. Using a Border is one alternative; a colored panel, shown below, is another.

You can also try calling `setOpaque(true)` on your button.

Comment: I am calling it when the button is clicked

Comment: +1 More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852024/230513).