# How do I use GridBayLayout in Java (Swing) to generate this particular image in my frame?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

[image: Desired main GUI]

Basically, how do I generate this?  I'm pretty sure this is a job for `GridBagLayout`, but I'm unable to wrap my head around how to properly size the 'Action Pane' versus the 'Menubar'.  The red & black lines indicate the grid that I believe you are to use in this case (3x3), but I might be completely wrong and there could be a way to do it in a different configuration.  I tried to mess around with the `weightx`, `weighty`, `gridheight`, `gridwidth` values in `GridBagConstraints`, but I can't achieve my goals here.

Note that the second red line is supposed to be exactly one-third of the height of the bottom half of the frame.

This is my latest attempt, by trying to use a 3x6 grid (c is the GridBagConstraints object, characterPortraits contain all the portraits, and currentScreen is the 'Action Pane') :

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 0.25;
    c.weighty = (1/6);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    pane.add(characterPortraits.get(0), c);  

    c.gridx = 2;        
    pane.add(characterPortraits.get(1), c);          

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    pane.add(characterPortraits.get(2), c);  

    c.gridx = 2;        
    pane.add(characterPortraits.get(3), c);

    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    pane.add(currentScreen, c);
```

Instead, this produces each portrait in the bottom third of its quadrant, and the Action Pane taking 5/6 of the center column instead of 4/6, like I want it to.  Any ideas would help; thanks! -B.

EDIT: I'm designing this application to have a fixed window size; people may say this is bad design, but I'm really just trying to get a feel for Swing components and make sure they at least behave in a fixed window the way I want them to.  I think I may allow for a maximize proper-resizing, but that's about it.

Comment: If the window stretches, what components do you want to take the available space (horizontal and vertical)?

Comment: all of elements are resiziable ???

Comment: Thanks for the questions; addressed them in the edit I just made.

Comment: Have you tried using a 3x3 grid, set all weights to 1, set sizes for the ActionPane and MenuBar, let the ActionPane, Portrait2, and Portrait4 span two cells vertically?  If you're targeting a window of a fixed size, setting the sizes of two components (or even 6) bother you...

Comment: Look at miglayout. It's easier to use for this than gridbaglayout.

Comment: *"may allow for a maximize proper-resizing, but that's about it."*  If you can get it to work for 2 sizes, it should work for anything in between.

Comment: BTW - if the 'red lines' indicate 1/3, does that mean that portraits 2 & 4 are twice the height of portraits 1 & 3?  While I admire your effort at posting a mock-up, I can't say I understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though, it appeared strange to me that you adding your `JMenuBar`, at the most weird of positions. Though what you can do, to overcome the difficulty mentioned by you in this line

```
Instead, this produces each portrait in the bottom third of its quadrant, and the 
Action Pane taking 5/6 of the center column instead of 4/6, like I want it to.
```

is to add one `JPanel` at this location and put your `ActionPane` and `JmenuBar` to this added `JPanel`, to achieve the desired outcome. So I had added `centerPanel` at this location to demonstrate, how this can be achieved.

I hope this output is what you so desired :

[image: OUTPUT]

And here is the code responsible for this output :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagPanelLayout
{
    private JPanel portrait1;
    private JPanel portrait2;
    private JPanel portrait3;
    private JPanel portrait4;
    private JPanel centerPanel;

    private JPanel actionPane;

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBag JPanel Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /*
         * This JPanel will serve as the 
         * Content Pane, for the JFrame.
         */
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.33;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;

        portrait1 = new JPanel();
        portrait1.setOpaque(true);
        portrait1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        portrait1.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                            2, 2, 2, 2, Color.WHITE));
        contentPane.add(portrait1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.gridheight = 4;

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constCenter = new GridBagConstraints();
        constCenter.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        constCenter.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constCenter.gridx = 0;
        constCenter.gridy = 0;
        constCenter.weightx = 1.0;
        constCenter.weighty = 0.975;

        actionPane = new JPanel();
        actionPane.setOpaque(true);
        actionPane.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        actionPane.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                            2, 2, 2, 2, Color.WHITE));
        centerPanel.add(actionPane, constCenter);

        constCenter.gridx = 0;
        constCenter.gridy = 1;
        constCenter.weighty = 0.025;

        centerPanel.add(getMenuBar(), constCenter); 
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, gbc);  

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;

        portrait3 = new JPanel();
        portrait3.setOpaque(true);
        portrait3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        portrait3.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                            2, 2, 2, 2, Color.WHITE));
        contentPane.add(portrait3, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        //gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        //gbc.gridheight = 2;

        portrait2 = new JPanel();
        portrait2.setOpaque(true);
        portrait2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        portrait2.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                            2, 2, 2, 2, Color.WHITE));
        contentPane.add(portrait2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;

        portrait4 = new JPanel();
        portrait4.setOpaque(true);
        portrait4.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        portrait4.setBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                            2, 2, 2, 2, Color.WHITE));
        contentPane.add(portrait4, gbc);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JMenuBar getMenuBar()
    {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setOpaque(true);
        fileMenu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        fileMenu.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("NEW");
        JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("OPEN");
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        fileMenu.add(openItem);

        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        editMenu.setOpaque(true);
        editMenu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        editMenu.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JMenuItem redoItem = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        JMenuItem undoItem = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        editMenu.add(redoItem);
        editMenu.add(undoItem);

        JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
        viewMenu.setOpaque(true);
        viewMenu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        viewMenu.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        JMenuItem zInItem = new JMenuItem("Zoom In");
        JMenuItem zOutItem = new JMenuItem("Zoom Out");
        viewMenu.add(zInItem);
        viewMenu.add(zOutItem);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(viewMenu);
        menuBar.setOpaque(true);
        menuBar.setBackground(Color.BLACK);     

        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBagPanelLayout().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @nIcE cOw : Thanks for the commentary and code!  That's pretty close to what I want, except for the fact that my "menubar" is not meant to be a `JMenuBar`, this is probably my mistake for being unclear with calling it my "menubar".  It is really just a fancy menu-LIKE bar with similar options, but with custom colours and a mouse-over custom picture attached along with it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Curious... if I specify the `weightx` in the beginning as 0.33 then it works how you displayed it, but if I specify it more exactly as (1 / 3), then the portraits appear smooshed into the center and very small - why is this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that was `NIGHT` time when you send that message. I guess the answer is in the basics of the Java Language, the result of division of two `Integer` values is also an `Integer`, so the value goes to the `result variable` after `Casting` which is zero, that's why. Try something like `1.0/3.0`, I guess that is the difference :-) Hence the `MORAL` exact way is `0.333` and not `1/3` :-)

Comment: Or you can write `(double) 1 / 3`

Comment: funny... I was writing `(double) (1 / 3)` before, but I guess the order-of-operations still made it cast to an integer instead.  Thanks again very much.

Comment: @BillyM. : Please do watch closely as to what I wrote ((double) 1 / 3), here first 1 will be cast to double than division by 3 is done. **Though in your case you wrote ((double) (1 / 3)), here first brackets are solved thus 1 divided by 3 will again give zero, and than the result will be cast to double. So answer will be something like 0.000 in your case** To watch the brackets in both the cases :-)

Answer (score 4):

I've never been a big fan of GridBagLayout. It's hard to get right - each component can have up to 11 constraints - it's hard to maintain, and reusing the same constraints object can lead to unintended consequences.

Instead, I prefer to nest various types of layout. To me, you clearly have:

1. A `BorderLayout`, with `West`, `Center`, and `East` panels
2. Inside the `West` panel, you have a `GridLayout` - 2 rows, 1 column (Portraits 1 and 2).
3. Inside the `East` panel, you have a `GridLayout` - 2 rows, 1 column (Portraits 3 and 4).
4. Inside the `Center` panel, you have another `BorderLayout`, with a `Center` component (Action Pane) and a `South` component (Menubar).

The only limitation to this is that the West panel and East panel are not logically connected. If Portraits 1, 2, 3, and 4 are all of the same size, that's not a problem. If they're of different sizes, you may find that the West and East panels will be shaped differently.

Comment: +1 for `Nested Layout`. If you want them to be of almost same size, you can first put a `JPanel` on `WEST/EAST/LINE_START/LINE_END` and then add `portrait JPanel` on top of that, that can lead to them having almost equal sizes. Please have a look at this example shown  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420311/java-swing-button-colors/3420431#3420431) by @trashgod and another one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369982/jbuttons-inside-jpanels-with-a-gridlayout-jframe/10372005#10372005).

Comment: No doubt, `GridBagLayout` is not easy to handle, though the outcome that one gets at the end is always pleasing.

Comment: I want to accept both of your answers, but I prefer nIcE cOw's above this because of the greater control and flexibility than `GridLayout` and `BorderLayout` provide.  Very good stuff here, though - thanks again.