# How to make a JPanel expand to max width in another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I feel I need to rephrase the question a bit.

***Updated question below.***

I have a JPanel that contains:

```
myjpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(selectors, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

**It contains the following three panels:**

JPanel with fixed size 'x' and 'y'

JPanel with no fixed size

JPanel with no fixed size and small height

The second JPanel contains a JTable so it expands to fill the full height and pushes the bottom panel all the way down, as expected.

*Like this:*

```
t
t
m
m
m
m
m
b
```

t = top panel,
m = middle panel,
b = bottom panel.

That works. But the bottom panel does not feel like filling the entire width of the parent which is a problem.

```
ttt
mmm
 b
```

I would like  either this, where the panel fills the entire width:

```
ttt
mmm
bbb
```

or this, where the bottom panel is left centered:

```
ttt
mmm
b
```

---

***Old question below:***

I have a JPanel that contains:

```
.setLayout(new BoxLayout(selectors, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

Within it, there are three more JPanels. The first two are of fixed size and the middle one isn't.

I want my bottom panel to take only the height it needs, but uses all the available width of the outer JPanel.

I have tried using glue but to no avail, and I would rather not set preferred and min/max sizes.
Is there a way to tell the component to "Fill the entire parents width" using just the layout manager and framework. I would rather not start to do hacks like setting sizes and overriding methods.

**Note:** I can't put any glue or filler in the inner panel, only the outer panel and its layout manager can be modified.

*Attempt 1:*

Using `myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));` did not produce the expected results. It made a grid like this:

```
XX
 X
```

But I expected:

```
X
X
X
```

*Attempt 2:*

Using `myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));` did not produce the expected results. It made a grid like this:

```
x
x
x
```

But all panels were of the same size, ignoring the restraints.

Comment: Its non-resizable at the moment. And its already there

Comment: I am using BoxLayout as it says in the question, but i will try a borderlayout instead. Just a moment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using a `BorderLayout` and the `b` panel is in the `SOUTH` or `PAGE_END` it does fill the entire width.

Comment: BorderLayout works perfectly. Thank you, and damn BoxLayout:)

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way would be to use another layout manager such as `GridLayout` that automatically sizes components to fill the parent container.

```
myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

Comment: ... or FormLayout from JGoodies

Comment: Would that screw with the two fixed size components that shares the container?

Comment: Alternatively i would be more than satisfied by left aligning the inner component as well, but i cant seem to do so as the setAllignmentX method doesn't do squat

Comment: I tried GridLayout, it did not arrange the components vertically but placed them 2 in the top and 1 in the buttom

Comment: @MartinNielsen : You have to use it like `new GridLayout(0, 1);`

Comment: GridLayout makes all the components equally large. The idea was that the bottom one should only be sized after its internal components.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), for that, using

```
gridBagObject.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL
```

One [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166903/1057230) for your help, relating to GridBagLayout.

**As asked in comments, related to that**

The [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) is another alternative, that respects the preferred sizes of the components. You can try that if GridBagLayout is that tough :-)

Code with GridBagLayout, for more clarity :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Gagandeep Bali
 * Date: 1/10/13
 * Time: 7:43 PM
 */
public class GridBagExample
{
    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        CustomPanel topPanel = new CustomPanel(Color.BLUE.darker().darker());
        CustomPanel middlePanel = new CustomPanel(Color.CYAN.darker().darker());
        CustomPanel bottomPanel = new CustomPanel(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.3;

        contentPane.add(topPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(middlePanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        contentPane.add(bottomPanel, gbc);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBagExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    public CustomPanel(Color backGroundColour)
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(backGroundColour);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(200, 150));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: GridBagExampleOutput]

Comment: Is there no simpler way? Keep in mind its just three components in a vertical row. It should not be required to go to the big guns. I just want my bottom component to use the full width. Surely i don't need to go gridbagconstraints for this?

Comment: @MartinNielsen : Please have a look at BoxLayout, as edited in my answer.

Comment: Ehm. I don't think you read the question. I AM using BoxLayout!

Answer (score -2):

Here some custom JPanel is used to expanding and shrinking with static input values.
Java timer is using to Delay and speed up the panel display time.

```
 public class SlidingPanel extends JPanel {
 private int paneHeight;
 private int paneWidth;
 private int comHeight;
 private int comWidth;
 private Timer everyspeedmillisec;

/**custom class for slide up and down actions for JPanel
 * 
 */

public SlidingPanel(LayoutManager layout,Dimension panedim) {

    super(layout);  
    setPreferredSize(panedim);
    paneHeight = (int)panedim.getHeight();;
    paneWidth  = (int) panedim.getWidth(); 

}

    /**function for expanding Jpanel
 * 
 */

public void expand_sft_det(int speed ,JPanel slidingcom)
{

 //Add Jpanel for sliding 

    this.add(slidingcom);
```

//Get height and width for panel ,that what we want to display as slide height.

```
 comHeight=(int)slidingcom.getMinimumSize().getHeight();

 comWidth=(int) slidingcom.getMinimumSize().getWidth();
```

//Intializing timer with some static values - Medium speed)

```
   everyspeedmillisec = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {


       private int count_timer=0; 

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       count_timer++;

         if( paneHeight < comHeight){

             setPreferredSize(new Dimension(paneWidth, paneHeight));

             paneHeight+=20;

             repaint();

             revalidate();

         }
         else

             everyspeedmillisec.stop() ;
    }


  });


  everyspeedmillisec.start(); 


}
```

/**function for Shrinking Jpanel
     * 
     */

```
public void shrink_sft_det(int speed ,JPanel slidingcom) {

 comHeight    = (int)slidingcom.getMinimumSize().getHeight();

     comWidth     = (int)slidingcom.getMinimumSize().getWidth();
```

//height for slide up to top position

```
     paneHeight=0;

     everyspeedmillisec = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {

     private int count_timer=0;

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     count_timer++; 

     if( paneHeight < comHeight){

           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(comWidth,comHeight));

           comHeight-=20;

           repaint();

           revalidate();

     }
     else
       everyspeedmillisec.stop() ;

 }

});
everyspeedmillisec.start();
```

}

//Declare class and using shrinking onclick event

```
public class SoftPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
, MouseListener {

JPanel MoredetPane;

JPanel SlidedetPane;

private JLabel SoftDOCLabel;

private JLabel SoftLocation;

private JLabel SoftUpdates;

private boolean mr_det_flag =true;



MoredetPane = new SlidingPanel(new GridLayout(1,1,5,5),new Dimension(300,1));

MoredetPane.setOpaque(false);

//Add some components 

        SlidedetPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2,50,25));

        SlidedetPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));

        SlidedetPane.setOpaque(false);

                SoftDOCLabel = new JLabel("Software Date") ;

            SoftLocation = new JLabel("Software Location") ;

        SoftUpdates  = new JLabel("Software Updates") ;


        SlidedetPane.add(SoftDOCLabel);

        SlidedetPane.add(new JLabel(softbean.getSoftDOC()));

        SlidedetPane.add(SoftLocation);

        SlidedetPane.add(new JLabel(softbean.getSoftPath()));  

        SlidedetPane.add( SoftUpdates);

        SlidedetPane.add(new JLabel(""));  

//Onclick events

      modedetails_Label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


       @Override
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent clickeve) {

           if(mr_det_flag){

              mr_det_flag=false;

                  ((SlidingPanel)MoredetPane).expand_sft_det(200,SlidedetPane);

                  add(SlidingPanel);
            }
            else{

            mr_det_flag=true;

          ((SlidingPanel) MoredetPane).shrink_sft_det(0,SlidedetPane);

            }


          });


    add( MoredetPane );

     }
```