# Create Swing GUI with vertically stacked sections

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I want to create a GUI in Swing which contains two vertical sections:

```
+-----------------------+
| labels,textfields     |
|   and buttons         |
+-----------------------+
|                       |
| chart display         |
|                       |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
```

I want the first section to take about 30% of the vertical space and the second about 70%.
How can I achieve this with Java Swing?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11166903/1057230), might can help you in that :-) Just use two `JPanel`s as top and bottom and use `GridBagConstraints` providing `weighty = 0.3 for upper JPanel` and `weighty = 0.7 for the lower JPanel`, `weightx = 1.0 for both the JPanel`, that will do.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: See VerticalLayout from SwingLabs SwingX library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also [`JSplitPane.setDividerLocation(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation%28int%29) & [How to Use Split Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend using `GridBagLayout` for the cases in which you want to controll the size of the layout's components as it allows to put weights on the components.

[How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use a layout manager like `BorderLayout`. The top one would go to `BorderLayout.NORTH`, the bigger one to `BorderLayout.CENTER`.