# Changing label text using ActionListener

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel, settext

I'm trying to make a program that allows me to change the text of a label when clicking different buttons, however regardless of what button I click the text of the label changes to the last line of `actionPerformed`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame{
private JButton add;
private JButton subtract;
private JButton multiply;
private JButton divide;
private JTextField box1;
private JTextField box2;
private JLabel label;
private JButton ansbutton;
public String operator;


public Gui(){
    super("Luke's Calculator");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add = new JButton("Add");
    subtract = new JButton("Subtract");
    multiply = new JButton("Multiply");
    divide = new JButton("Divide");
    add(add);
    add(subtract);
    add(multiply);
    add(divide);
    box1 = new JTextField(10);
    label = new JLabel();
    box2 = new JTextField(10);
    ansbutton = new JButton("Answer");
    add(box1);
    add(label);
    add(box2);
    add(ansbutton);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    add.addActionListener(handler);
    subtract.addActionListener(handler);
    multiply.addActionListener(handler);
    divide.addActionListener(handler);
    ansbutton.addActionListener(handler);
}
public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public double sum;
    public double fn;
    public double sn;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(add.isSelected())
            operator = "+";
        label.setText("+");

        if(subtract.isSelected())
            operator = "-";
        label.setText("-");

        if(multiply.isSelected())
            operator = "x";
        label.setText("x");

        if(divide.isSelected())
            operator = "/";
        label.setText("/");

        if(ansbutton.isSelected())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer is " + sum, "Answer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Use brackets to wrap each if clause and use "else if"  after the first if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not including the `label.setText()` method inside your `if` statements. Because of this it will execute every `label.setText()` call and keep overriding the text until it defaults to the final call in your method. It is better to use braces, even for one line `if` statements, to avoid this problem.

```
 if(e.getSource() == add) {
    operator = "+";
    label.setText("+");
}
```

Also, since only one of the conditions is going to be true, you can use an `else if`.

Comment: I'm really confused, I've done what you said and now instead of changing to the last one it does not change at all! Any ideas?

Comment: @LukeHebblethwaite Try changing the condition in your `if` statements to this: `if(e.getSource() == add)` etc...

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you! Do you have any idea why my way didn't work? I'm interested as to why it would not work

Comment: @LukeHebblethwaite `isSelected()` only really works for toggle buttons. Using `e.getSource()` checks which object specifically triggered the `ActionEvent` and is therefore what you want to use for normal buttons.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337659/jbutton-isselected-method-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if(add.isSelected())
        operator = "+";
    label.setText("+");
```

You have no curly brackets after the if, so only setting the operator is conditional, the label is ALWAYS changed. So the last label always win.

```
if(add.isSelected()) {
        operator = "+";
    label.setText("+");
}
```

Or

```
if(add.isSelected())
        operator = "+";
...
label.setText(operator)
```

Comment: I'm really confused, I've done what you said and now instead of changing to the last one it does not change at all! Any ideas?