# How do I set a JButton's fill color?

Tags: java, swing, button, colors

How do I?  Can I?

```
public class Jbutton {
    public static void main (String[] args){
    JButton button = new JButton("I'm colorful!");
    button.
```

What do I do here ^ to set the button color?

```
    }
}
```

Comment: `button.setBackground`?

Comment: Have you checked out the javadoc?

Comment: What the heck. Why do you keep asking questions that can be answered by simply looking things up? Why the lazy questions? Part of the skill set of being a decent programmer is learning how to find this information on your own, and you might wish to exercise this skill just a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options either use `setBackground` or `setIcon` E.g.

1. button.setBackground(myColor);
2. button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(pathToIcon));

Comment: now how do I get it to turn red then turn back to the default color?

Comment: @CadeLikesToCode you can use javax.swing.Timer

Comment: Just beware that using `setBackground` may not affect the "content area" of the button on some look and feels and could be ignored if the button is transparent...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thats why Included 2 options

Comment: What's the syntax for the timer @sol4me?

Comment: @sol4me I have no issue with your answer, it's just a FYI ;).  If you didn't want the content area fill affect, you can actually turn it off ;)

Comment: @CadeLikesToCode That's beyond the scope of the original question, but take a look [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: @CadeLikesToCode better post a new question because its out of scope for this question

Comment: @MadProgrammer Understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe its like so

```
{
JButton btn = new       
JButton(String.valueOf(i));
btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
btn.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
p3.add(btn);
}
```

Using my phone so trouble editing it to post code, that's what I used on a previous project though if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Using your example:

```
public class Jbutton {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //You're going to need some context for this like a JFrame
        JButton button = new JButton("I'm colorful!");
        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Though I think for a more enlightening section of code, you might explore [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959053/jframe-buttons-that-change-background-color-of-window) to see how some parts of swing and AWT work.