# how to change the jbutton color while the user is clicking on it ?

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I developed a virtual keyboard with `JButton`s. 
How do I change the color of the `JButton` while I am pressing it (with the mouse or keyboard) and revert back to the original color after leaving it ?

Comment: `setBackground(color)` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a JButton color on mouse pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)

Comment: Either you can use a simple 'mouseListener' and 'setBackground(color)' when mouse is clicked or you can use different LOOK AND FEEL User Interfaces that gives such facility without really setting something.

Comment: closeparenthesis_0=new JButton("<html>)<br/>0");                             v    
        add(closeparenthesis_0);                                            Can someone show me an example of how to register after these commands?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original background color of your button in the **oldColor** java.awt.Color variable. A MouseAdapter is a convenient way to avoid clutter.

You will just need to override `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()`:

```
    ...
    oldColor = jButton1.getBackground();
    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            jButton1.setBackground(Color.green);
            doWhateverYouHaveToDo();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            jButton1.setBackground(oldColor);
        }
    };
    jButton1.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    ...
```

Comment: if i have a defulte color in jbutton how i return this color?

Comment: oldColor=jButton1.getBackground(); keeps the default color, so you can set it back after your mouse has been released.