# Making the contents of a JFrame stretch if window is maximized and coloring of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

Is there any way to color a JButton? I want to change it's color after it's pressed to show that it has been pressed. Is there a way that I can do this?

Also, in a JFrame, is there a way to make it so that the whole contents of the window will stretch to the fill the frame when the window is maximized?

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: *"I want to change it's color after it's pressed to show that it has been pressed"* Do you want the button to stay pressed?  What if they press it again?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link for changing JButton color on every state.

[How to change a JButton color on mouse pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)

For the `JFrame`, you can set the Layout of the `JFrame` to `BorderLayout` and add the `JPanel` in the center of the `JFrame`, so it will fill all the `JFrame` even when resized.

Example:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: What if I'm using a FlowLayout? Do you know of any easy way to do this so I don't have to redo the whole program with a BorderLayout instead?

Comment: You're using FlowLayout for what, the JFrame or the JPanel ? @user3268401

Comment: @user3268401 If for the JFrame, then remove what was added to the JFrame and add them to a new JPanel of Layout FlowLayout. Then this JPanel add it to the JFrame of BorderLayout in the Center using the above example in my answer

Comment: @user3268401 No, `FlowLayout` repects the preferred size of the component, therefore it won't be appropriate.  `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` all provide the functionality you're looking for

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why borderLayout is not appropriate ? Btw I agree that you can achieve this also with GridLayout and GridBagLayout

Comment: @AmirBawab I agree that `BorderLayout` is one of the layout managers that would achieve this, `FlowLayout` can't, sorry if I didn't make myself clear the first time