# Best way to handle a MouseClick on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
public class Square extends JButton {   
    ... 
}
```

What's the best way for a JButton to handle a MouseClick that changes the background color of itself?  Do I want to add/overwrite an ActionListener/MouseListener/etc?

Comment: Use `JButton#setBackground()` to change the background color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change a JButton color on mouse pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)

Comment: -1: What have you tried already, for yourself?

Comment: I've tried both, and both have worked, I'm just wondering what is the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to add an `ActionListener` and do your mumbo-jumbo in `actionPerformed()`. Use the `setBackground()` to change the background color. :)

Comment: just beware, that on some look and feels, setting the backgoround can have no effect ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer and that is because ... ? :)

Comment: That's what the OP wants to do.  Right answer, just need to beware of it, that's all ;)