# How to change the background color of a grid cell on mouse over? (GXT)

Tags: java, listener, gxt

How can I change the background color of a **grid cell** on mouse over in **GXT (Java)**?

I want to change the background color of a grid cell when the mouse is over the cell, from the code, not from the CSS. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what is your problem using css?

Comment: @DanielStiefel, I don't have rights to modify the CSS files. I have to do it dynamically, from the code :).

Comment: if you can edit the xhtml files, you can try it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094859/how-to-set-the-background-color-for-hcommandbutton-in-backing-bean)

Comment: @DanielStiefel, thank you! But I have to do it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 grid.addStyleOnOver(grid.getElement(), styleClass);
```

You can get style from *.gss file or create your own style by

```
StyleInjector.inject(".myStyle {background-color: yellow;}");
grid.addStyleOnOver(grid.getElement(), "myStyle");
```