# Change JButton's click color?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've created some swing applications involving `JButton`s, and noticed whenever one is clicked, it turns white. Example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15BJ8.jpg).

How would I change it so when, and only when, the button is clicked, it turns RED instead of the usual white, and when it is released, it goes back to its normal look? Is there a method for this?

Example code:

```
JButton b = new JButton("foo");
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){


        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            //turn red
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            //go back to original state
        }

    });
```

Comment: we can to press that button using keyboard also not only with mouse then

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change color of button text using `setForeground` method

like this

```
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            b.setForeground(Color.red); // button text color
            // b.setBackground(Color.red); // button background color
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            b.setForeground(Color.black); // button text color
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton b = new JButton("foo");
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //go back to original state
    }

});
```

For more details look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)