# How to change JButton background colour while it is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jbutton

I am trying to override the default background colour of the `JButton` while it is pressed; the background colour must stay as long as the button is still pressed.

I tried this code:

```
 button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        button.setBackground(Color.BLUE); // applied after release!!
        System.out.println("pressed"); // applied on pressed - OK.
    }
});}
```

`mousePressed` here doesn't achieve my requirement!!

This line is never invoked: `button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);`. But this line is invoked: `System.out.println("pressed");`.

However this line `button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);` is invoked after releasing the button - Not while pressed!!!

How to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Try setting the contentFilled property to false and opaque to true

Comment: Maybe this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

Before your mouse-adapter part of code, make a `Color` object as:

```
final Color col = button.getBackground();
```

Then, in your mouse adapter, add this method:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    button.setBackground(col);
}
```

This makes your total code to :

```
final Color col = b.getBackground();

button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        b.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        b.setBackground(g);
    }
});
```

So, when you press, the color changes to blue, and then when you release the mouse, it changes back to original. This works fine on my computer.