# Is there a way to change the 'Selected' color of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Im looking for a way to change the colour of the 'Selected' state of a JButton. I am aware of background color but that only changes the not selected colour?

Comment: Check this Question: [How to change a JButton color on mouse pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed)