# How to change the background color of a Jbutton on click

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I'm trying to change the color of a JButton when you click on it, but a blue color appears instead of the one I wrote about.

**Goal**: The goal is that when you click on the button the color change

I did several searches, but each time a blue font appeared.

I tried overide paintComponent, several alternatives such as this.getModel, but nothing works.

My button class:

```
package com.tralamy.lancherX.display;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TButton extends JButton {

    private Color hoverColor = Display.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private Color pressColor = Display.LIGHT_DARK;
    private Color firstColor;
    private Color basic;

    private MouseAdapter hoverAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            basic = firstColor;
            TButton.this.setBackground(hoverColor);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            TButton.this.setBackground(basic);
        }
    };

    private MouseAdapter pressAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            TButton.this.setBackground(pressColor);
            super.mousePressed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            TButton.this.setBackground(basic);
            super.mouseReleased(e);
        }
    };

    public TButton (String text){
        super(text);
        init();
    }

    public TButton (Icon icon){
        super(icon);
        init();
    }

    public TButton (){
        super();
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        firstColor = this.getBackground();
        setBorder(null);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setOpaque(false);
        setFocusPainted(false);
        setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon());
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg) {
        super.setBackground(bg);
        firstColor = bg;
    }

    public void setHover()
    {
        this.addMouseListener(hoverAdapter);
    }

    public void removeHover()
    {
        this.removeMouseListener(hoverAdapter);
    }

    public void setPress()
    {
        this.addMouseListener(pressAdapter);
    }

    public void removePress()
    {
        this.removeMouseListener(pressAdapter);
    }

    public void setHoverColor(Color color)
    {
        hoverColor = color;
    }

    public Color getHoverColor()
    {
        return hoverColor;
    }

    public Color getPressColor() {
        return pressColor;
    }

    public void setPressColor(Color pressColor) {
        this.pressColor = pressColor;
    }
}
```

Main menu panel:

```
private JPanel menuPanel() {
        mp = new JPanel();
        setPercentWidth(mp, 25);

        mp.setBackground(LIGHT_GRAY);
        mp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel userSection = new JPanel();
        userSection.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        setPercentHeight(userSection, 5);
        userSection.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(userSection.getWidth(), 0));
        userSection.setBackground(LIGHT_DARK);

        userIconButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        userName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        userIconButton.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,10));

        userSection.add(userIconButton);
        userSection.add(userName);

        menuButtons.add(new TButton("Library"));
        menuButtons.add(new TButton("Store"));
        menuButtons.add(new TButton("Friends"));
        menuButtons.add(new TButton("News"));


        JPanel menuSection = new JPanel();
        menuSection.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuSection, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        menuSection.setOpaque(false);

        for (TButton button : menuButtons) {
            button.setAlignmentX(TButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

            button.setFont(App.setSemiBoldNunito(48));

            button.setForeground(SUPER_SUPER_LIGHT_GRAY);

            button.setBackground(SUPER_LIGHT_GRAY);

            button.setBorder(null);
            button.setBorderPainted(true);
            button.setContentAreaFilled(true);
            button.setOpaque(true);

            button.setHoverColor(DARK_GRAY);
            button.setHover();

            button.setPressColor(LIGHT_DARK);
            button.setPress();

            TButton marginLabel = new TButton();

            marginLabel.setSize(MAIN_MENU_MARGIN, MAIN_MENU_MARGIN);
            marginLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(MAIN_MENU_MARGIN, MAIN_MENU_MARGIN));
            marginLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(MAIN_MENU_MARGIN, MAIN_MENU_MARGIN));

            setPercentWidth(button, 20);

            menuSection.add(marginLabel);
            
            menuSection.add(button);

        }

        mp.add(menuSection);
        mp.add(userSection, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return mp;
    }
```

And then some image:
[My bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz3hp.png%3C)

And thank you in advance

Comment: try setBackground. You may also want to look at JToggleButton

Comment: @ControlAltDel it's wath i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the background of the button with a persistent color when the user clicks on the button, then you can use `setContentAreaFilled(false)` on it. Then it is required to reset the opaque property to `true` because according to [the docs of `setContentAreaFilled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled-boolean-): "*This function may cause the component's opaque property to change.*", for example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainPersist {
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JButton button = new JButton("Click to change color");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            button.setOpaque(true); //Reset the opacity.
            button.setBackground(Color.CYAN.darker()); //Set your desired color as the background.
        });
        
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button bg on click");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainPersist::createAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want the button to only change its color when clicked and then return back to normal when released, then take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314374/how-can-i-override-the-default-mousepressed-background-color-of-all-jbuttons-int) which is about exactly that. It has no accepted answers yet (it is very recent as of the time this answer itself is posted), but there is at least one/my answer (which suggests to modify the `ButtonUI` of the button) and there should be more answers coming I guess.

Comment: No problem. Also note that the other question I linked, is linking to an even better question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627223/how-to-change-a-jbutton-color-on-mouse-pressed