# Add specific background colors to JDaychooser Dates

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

I've developed a Java Swing application..

How can I set the background color of specific JDayChooser dates?

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome; sorry about the mispelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    JPanel jPanel = jDayChooser1.getDayPanel();

    Component component[] = jPanel.getComponents();

    for (int i = 7; i < 49; i++) {
        component[i].setBackground(Color.red);
    }
```

Finally got a solution to do :D

Answer (score 2):

**getDayPanel**

```
public javax.swing.JPanel getDayPanel()
```

This returns the day panel. After that, you can:

```
panel.setBackground(color);
```

Also:

**setForeground**

```
public void setForeground(java.awt.Color foreground)
```

Sets the foregroundColor color.

**setDecorationBackgroundColor**

```
public void setDecorationBackgroundColor(java.awt.Color decorationBackgroundColor)
```

Sets the background of days and weeks of year buttons.

Comment: JPanel jPanel = jDayChooser1.getDayPanel();
        
        Component component[] = jPanel.getComponents();
       
        for (int i = 7; i < 49; i++) {
            component[i].setBackground(Color.red);
        }

Comment: glad you find the solution and thanks for the feedback. + 1 for your answer. Tip: don't forget marking your own answer as correct. It will give you reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

`JDayChooser` has a `protected` field that specifies the `selectedColor`, but it has no public   interface. You can,

- Alter the default gray, in `JDayChooser#init()`.
- Add the required methods; the new bound property will appear in `JCalendarDemo`.

  ```
  public Color getSelectedColor() {
      return selectedColor;
  }

  public void setSelectedColor(Color selectedColor) {
      this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
  }
  ```

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513), `setBackground()` doesn't read well on some Look & Feel implementations. The workaround in `DecoratorButton#paint()` is an example.