# Getting NullPointerException in JPanel jPanel = jDayChooser1.getDayPanel()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, calendar, jdatechooser

In this i'm trying to get the dates from mysql database and display those dates in a jDayChooser by setting a color.But in `JPanel jPanel = jDayChooser1.getDayPanel()` im getting the error 'NullPointerException'.

```
public Calender() {

// retrieving the dates from db

  getDates c = new getDates();
  Date[] a = c.Dates();

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

  JPanel jPanel = jDayChooser1.getDayPanel();

  Component component[] = jPanel.getComponents();

  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
      if(month == a[i].getMonth() && year == a[i].getYear()) {
         component[ a[i].getDay()].setBackground(Color.blue);
      }
  }

  initComponents();
}
```

here's the stack trace...

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at greetingcard.Calender.<init>(Calender.java:37)
        at greetingcard.Calender$1.run(Calender.java:100)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)`

Comment: Add your stack trace.

Comment: I added the stack trace :)

Comment: where are you creating `jDayChooser1` ??

Comment: Its in the jFrame i have created..does it make any difference?

Comment: Looks like jDayChooser1 is null at that point. How/where do you create it?

Comment: This is the first time im trying to do a event calendar in java by using jDayChooser.I did some searching and found from [Add specific background colors to JDaychooser Dates.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234388/add-specific-background-colors-to-jdaychooser-dates) Isn't `jDayChooser1` the jDayChooser we add in the jframe from component palette ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured it out.. :)

```
 public Calender() {
 initComponents();

// retrieving the dates from db

getDates c = new getDates();
Date[] a = c.Dates();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

JPanel jPanel = jDayChooser1.getDayPanel();

Component component[] = jPanel.getComponents();

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    if(month == a[i].getMonth() && year == a[i].getYear()) {
     component[ a[i].getDay()].setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
}

initComponents();
}
```