# Refresh RangeEvaluator in a JCalendar

Tags: java, user-interface, jcalendar

I'm trying to create a calendar to display and modify a schedule. To do this I have to change the color of some dates in that calendar. I have followed [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjcalendar%5D%20RangeEvaluator) that created a `RangeEvaluator` and managed to highlight the dates. The problem is that if I click that date (and I need to in order to modify it from busy to free for exemple) its color goes back to normal.
Here is my code:

```
RangeEvaluator evaluator = new RangeEvaluator();
//get dates from DB:
    Vector<Date> vd=SA.getCalendrier(transport);
    evaluator.setVd(vd);
    calendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37899883/230513), your `IDateEvaluator` is probably returning specific foreground and background colors to highlight the dates. Note that the foreground color remains set when you click a highlighted date button. In contrast, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252102/230513), the background color belongs to the chosen Look & Feel. I'd rely on foreground color and tooltip; I'd consider background color highlighting optional.

As a workaround, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25501373/230513), you can set a bound property in your `PropertyChangeListener` to reconfigure the buttons, but the selected button will *still* be rendered according to the Look & Feel. Select a button that's *not* highlighted to see the effect.

```
JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();
jc.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator);
jc.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
jc.addPropertyChangeListener("calendar", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        jc.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        …
    }
});
```

More generally, note that `JCalendar` is a date *chooser*, not a day *planner*.