# Setting background color to JButton

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I have a question about setting the background color to `JButton`.

It seems that the this method only changes the color of the border. Here is the difference (left is `jButton`):

[image]

Is there a way to make the background the same?

I'm using `setLookAndFeel` on Windows 8.

Comment: See also [*Java Swing button colors*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3420311/230513).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will work with either the Metal (default) or Windows PLAFs.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

class ColoredButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
            b1.setBackground(Color.RED);
            // these next two lines do the magic..
            b1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            b1.setOpaque(true);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b1);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i needed to add setContentAreaFilled(false)
now it works great

Comment: setContentAreaFilled did the trick for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use .setOpaque(true) on the button.

Comment: it does not seem to work, the result is still only the border becoming red