# Java colored buttons only on edges

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am trying to create a grid with randomly colored buttons. I was able to create the grid, add buttons to it and even create a random color- only issue is the color is only showing up on the edges of the buttons. I even tried using the button.setForeground(color) as a possible solution but it did not work. I want the entire button to be colored with my randomly generated color. How can I do so?[image]

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            Color color = randomColorGenerator();
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
            buttons[i][j].setBackground(color);
            buttons[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            jp.add(buttons[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try also using `setContentAreaFilled` and `setBorderPainted` (and probably `setFocusPainted`) passing them `false`

Comment: The answer referred to explains how to add an image to a JButton with a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons[i][j].setBackground(color);
buttons[i][j].setContentAreaFilled(false);
buttons[i][j].setOpaque(true);
```

Should do the trick. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165160/setting-background-color-to-jbutton).
If you want to remove the border color, add this line:

```
buttons[i][j].setBorder(null);
```