# Changing JButton color After Applying L&F

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, uimanager

Is it possible to change jbutton color after applying the system default L&F? I've used this code in my main method before applying color changes:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
       | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately, the button appears as the default grey color, even after specifically setting the background color in this class:

```
public class ProperButton extends JButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5613675445790470261L;

     public ProperButton(String label) {
         super(label);
         this.setBackground(new Color(111, 111, 111));
     }

}
```

Comment: This is dependent on the LAF. If the LAF doesn't let you set the background color of a button then you can't.

Comment: in windows it not work

Comment: what could be an alternative?

Comment: Your code works, it just doesn't effect the main "content" area of the button.  In my testing it filled the around outside of the button

Comment: Some alternatives are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque(boolean)