# problems adding arrays of jbutton and jlabel into arrays of jpanel unto a frame

Tags: java, arrays, swing

i want to add 10 jlabel and 10 jbutton unto each jpanel. Now there are 10 jpanels which i want to add to a frame, so the jframe should show 100 jlabel, 100 jbutton with 10 jpanels.
My problem is that the frame only shows 10 jlabel and 10 jbutton. i dunno where am wrong.
here is my code

```
public class MultiPanel extends JFrame {

private JPanel[] panel;
private JLabel[] label;
private JButton[] button;

public MultiPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel[10];
    label = new JLabel[10];
    button = new JButton[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
        label[i] = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        button[i] = new JButton("B");
        label[i].setSize(50, 50);
        panel[i] = new JPanel();
        panel[i].setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        panel[i].add(label[i]);
        panel[i].add(button[i]);
        add(panel[i]);
    }
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 10));
    setSize(720, 560);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiPanel m_pnl = new MultiPanel();
}
}
```

Comment: Your logic is bad.. you are adding 10 jpanel, and in each panel 1 label and one button...

Comment: @nachokk: your comment is right, my answer is wrong. You should make that an answer.

Comment: Original poster -- you might be better using a JTable instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels offers a good suggestion; this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513) will scale into the hundreds, but not thousands.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did the dirty work and posted correct logic :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MultiPanel extends JFrame {

public MultiPanel() {
int increment = 0;
while(increment < 10){
    JPanel toAdd = new JPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        JButton b = new JButton("B");
        l.setSize(50, 50);
        toAdd.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        toAdd.add(l);
        toAdd.add(b);
    }
    add(toAdd);
    increment++;
}
setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 10));
setSize(720, 560);
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiPanel m_pnl = new MultiPanel();
}
}
```

Your logic was faulty... Try this. You have an outer `while`loop that will create 10 `JPanels` like you want. The inner `for` loop adds 10 `JLabels` and `JButtons` to each `JPanel`like you want. Then you just add all ten `JPanels` to the main `JPanel` which is slapped on the `JFrame`. I have compiled and run this and it works

Before you were only adding one label and button to each panel. You had 10 panels each with 1 button and one label

Comment: hi josh, i tried ur code but it gave me an array index out of bounds exception

Comment: I just compiled it and it ran fine...are you sure that everything is exactly as I have it

Comment: i ran it in a diffrent class so sorry @josh

Comment: I just made another edit removing all the arrays as you really dont need them so out of bounds exceptions should be gone