# Java Swing GridLayout stretched?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

So I have the following Java Code which produces what you see in the image. The layout is pretty much what I wanted except that the buttons are stretched to be equal size and fill. Is there anyway to avoid this without using GridBagLayout like other answers suggest? I tried setting the size of the panel inside to something smaller but it got stretched anyway.

**Code:**

```
    //Set-up main window
    JFrame mainwindow = new JFrame();
    mainwindow.setSize(500, 500);
    mainwindow.setTitle("Example");

    //Add components
    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0,2,0,5);
    JPanel pnl_Logon = new JPanel();
    pnl_Logon.setLayout(experimentLayout);
    JLabel lbl_Username = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JLabel lbl_Password = new JLabel("Password: ");
    JTextField txt_Username = new JTextField(10);
    JPasswordField psw_Password = new JPasswordField(10);
    JButton btn_Logon = new JButton("Logon");
    JButton btn_Clear = new JButton("Clear");
    pnl_Logon.add(lbl_Username);
    pnl_Logon.add(txt_Username);
    pnl_Logon.add(lbl_Password);
    pnl_Logon.add(psw_Password);
    pnl_Logon.add(btn_Logon);
    pnl_Logon.add(btn_Clear);

    tabs.addTab("Logon", pnl_Logon);

    //Draw window
    mainwindow.add(tabs);
    mainwindow.show();
```

**Result:**

[image: Java Layout]

Comment: The layout looks odd, but a "simple" solution (compared to GridBagLayout) could be to wrap the buttons into JPanels that each have a FlowLayout.

Comment: So each button would be in its own JPanel with Flow Layout? Then I would add each component to another JPanel to be added to the tab?

Comment: Use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: You should probably describe in more detail how the result should look like. You may want to replace the line `tabs.addTab("Logon", pnl_Logon);` with `JPanel p = new JPanel(); p.add(pnl_Logon); tabs.addTab("Logon", p);` to let it be layouted with its preferred size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridLayout` manager does not honour the minimum, preferred, and maximum
size values of its children. All the cells in `GridLayout` have the same size. 
The size of each cell is equal to the size of a cell with the largest component.
It is not a very useful manager and it seldom can be used in real-world applications.
But what it seems to do is to create confusion.

You mentioned that you would like to avoid the `GridBagLayout` manager. But there
are many other options. This kind of layout can be easily accomplised with more 
flexible managers.

I provide a simple solution with a `MigLayout` manager. `MigLayout` is a grid-based
layout manager too and this kind of layout can be easily created in a few lines.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;



public class MigLayoutLogin extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutLogin() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Log in");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("ins 15"));


        add(new JLabel("User name:"));
        add(new JTextField(10), "pushx, growx, wrap");
        add(new JLabel("Password: "));
        add(new JPasswordField(10), "growx, wrap");

        add(new JButton("Log in"), "span 2, split 2, center, gaptop 15");
        add(new JButton("Log out"));

        pack();
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutLogin ex = new MigLayoutLogin();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

I do not know how exactly you wanted this layout so I created it my way.
The text fields grow horizontally and the two buttons are horizontally
aligned to the center.

[image: Log in]

Answer (score 2):

For the reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), don't use `setSize()` this way. Instead, let each component adopt it's preferred size and `pack()` the enclosing `Window`. In this case, add each button to a panel having the default `FlowLayout`, which respects preferred size, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513).

[image]