# Customizing JButton borders

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border, jbutton

Is there a way, if so how, to add a border to a button but only to the bottom of it? I want to change the colour of the bottom border of the button. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [MatteBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/MatteBorder.html)? It could be as simple as button.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.RED));

Comment: No sorry, though I have searched it up. I am not familiar with the syntax. From what I have seen and understand, it is mostly related to icons etc. How would I implement a MattBorder to a JButton? would it be something similar to the following: Border solidBorder = new MatteBorder(10, 5, 2, 20, Color.RED) - but how do I assign it to a specific button?

Comment: Sorry, I have just seen your edit, Ill try it now. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code as Answer and then select it as correct answer. It will help others in future

Comment: I concur with @mprabhat; please don't hesitate to reference my answer in yours.

Answer (score 2):

A button's appearance is controlled by the UI delegate of the user's chosen Look & Feel. Borders applied directly to the button don't always appear. As suggested by the authors of [`setBorder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder-javax.swing.border.Border-), add the border [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195794/customizing-jbutton-borders#comment42876682_27195794) by @mprabhat to the button's surrounding container. Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513), I made the following change to the `ButtonPanel` constructor:

```
public ButtonPanel(int i) {
    this.setBackground(new Color(rnd.nextInt()));
    this.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.RED));
    this.add(new JButton("Button " + String.valueOf(i)));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow it just looks so nice, take 1 from me :)