# How to create a GUI grid and place every single results in each grid?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridview

I am trying to create a grid (5*5) size like GUI. I tried and made a very basic grid, which is working quite fine, but I am trying to change the background colour of each JPanel when user click and drop over it. But I am not aware of the GUI in Java yet. So wondering if someone could help me please.

This my code to the grid and matching the both files(Sentiment word analyzing)

```
    public static TwitterSystem getObject()
    {
        if (Object==null)
            Object = new TwitterSystem();
        return Object;
    }
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

    //read jason from file into String
            //create a lot of tweet objects

    //run the tweetSystem
    public void Run()
    {
        double r;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                DataGrid[i][j] = 0.0;

        // trying to load the wordlist and tweets
        try
        {
             WordList = new Sentiment_Analysis("E:\\JAVA\\src\\wordlist.txt");

             Tweet = new Tweet_Reader("E:\\JAVA\\tweets.json");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        tweets = Tweet.getTweets();


        // for each tweet, we getting the rating and working out where it is in the grid.
        for(Tweet t : tweets) {
            r = WordList.getRating(t);

            if((int)t.getCoordinate().getLatitude() == 24 && (int)t.getCoordinate().getLongitude() == 54 ) {
                DataGrid[2][2] += r;
            }
            if((int)t.getCoordinate().getLatitude() == 25 && (int)t.getCoordinate().getLongitude() == 54 ) {
                DataGrid[0][1] += r;
            }

        }

        // printing out the score for each square.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                System.out.format("[%4d][%4d] = %.4f\n", i, j, DataGrid[i][j]);
        System.out.println("Finish calculating");
        System.out.println("STATS - TIME: Analysis took "


                + TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(totalTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                + " seconds");
    }




}
```

Thank you in advance! i'm quite new to Programming

So far got the grid working but i want make the grid in GUI

HELP PLEASE!!!!

Comment: Hate to be a pain, but there is no Swing/UI related elements here...

Comment: You might like to take a look at [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's where i'm lost, i have a basic grid. but it's not in a great structure. you think you can help me ??

Comment: @MadProgrammer i know how to use a GUI grid code but it's not quite jamming with my codes!!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the response. I have minimized code to the right point!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513), I've added an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to each `ButtonPanel` in the grid. The listener updates the enclosing panel's background color. Note that each button uses its own *instance* of the same anonymous class. Comment out the timer's `start()` invocation to see the effect better. As an exercise, try changing class `ButtonPanel` to a factory method such as `createButtonPanel()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513) for `createGridPanel()`.

```
private static class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    public ButtonPanel(int i) {
        this.setBackground(new Color(rnd.nextInt()));
        JButton b = new JButton("Button " + String.valueOf(i));
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
                ButtonPanel.this.setBackground(new Color(rnd.nextInt()));
            }
        });
        this.add(b);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply... this kind a grid what i'm looking for, but it's not displaying my sentiment word results??

Comment: Now you have a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which to experiment; use it to update you question with a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); note that no one else has your word list, so you'll need to incorporate a some static data for completeness.

Comment: thank you for the example code it was useful, but i still coudn't make it get the results. sorry for asking silly question. My JAVA Knowladge is very minimum. also i have attached a link to my file. see if this can help fix my problem. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i6cb28dz6phwku4/AAAtdAaQmWjNI9pQEApirz6ka?dl=0

Comment: Correcting an entire project is well beyond the scope of SO. Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on a particular problem.

Comment: my particular problem is that I not able to construct a GUI grid

Comment: Well, a `GridLayout` of components works pretty well, but you should also look at `JList` and `JTable`.