# How can I set the dimension of some particular JButton component (in this case btnPlus)?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, grid-layout

I tried to use setSize() but didn't work. then I also used setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y)). Yes it does work but it changes the size of all the Components in that (oPanel) Panel. I just want to change the size of btnPlus.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame main= new JFrame();
    JPanel bPanel= new JPanel();
    JPanel oPanel= new JPanel();
    JPanel Txt= new JPanel();
    JPanel Panel=new JPanel();
    JButton btn0= new JButton("0");
    JButton btn1= new JButton("1");
    JButton btn2= new JButton("2");
    JButton btn3= new JButton("3");
    JButton btn4= new JButton("4");
    JButton btn5= new JButton("5");
    JButton btn6= new JButton("6");
    JButton btn7= new JButton("7");
    JButton btn8= new JButton("8");
    JButton btn9= new JButton("9");
    JButton btnDot= new JButton(".");
    JButton btnPlus= new JButton("+");
    JButton btnMinus= new JButton("-");
    JButton btnEquals= new JButton("=");
    //JTextField tf= new JTextField();
    JTextArea ta= new JTextArea();

    ta.setColumns(20);
    ta.setRows(3);
    //ta.setViewPortView()

    main.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20,20));

    Txt.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //Txt.add(tf,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Txt.add(ta,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    bPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,5,5));
    bPanel.add(btn0);
    bPanel.add(btn1);
    bPanel.add(btn2);
    bPanel.add(btn3);
    bPanel.add(btn4);
    bPanel.add(btn5);
    bPanel.add(btn6);
    bPanel.add(btn7);
    bPanel.add(btn8);
    bPanel.add(btn9);
    bPanel.add(btnDot);

    oPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,5,5));
    //oPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    oPanel.add(btnPlus);
    oPanel.add(btnMinus);
    oPanel.add(btnEquals);

    btnPlus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,100));
    btnMinus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25,25));
    btnPlus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,100));

    Panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    Panel.add(bPanel);
    Panel.add(oPanel);

    //main.getContentPane().add(bPanel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    //main.getContentPane().add(oPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    main.getContentPane().add(Panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    main.getContentPane().add(Txt, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    main.setSize(300, 300);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: *"How can I set the dimension of some particular JButton component (in this case btnPlus)?"* It is better not to.  Instead give it an icon, a font size and a margin to suggest a size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main problem is in the use of `GridLayout`, which gives equal space to all the components in the container based on the configuration you give it and the size of the container.

Consider instead, using a `GridBagLayout`, which will give you much more control.

See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details.

You should also take a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) and yes, you should be avoiding it

Comment: See also this nested layout [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513).