# xBased 64 Deployment Issue with Web Applications

Tags: java, netbeans

i have just installed Tomcat and added it as a server on Netbeans. when i try to launch my web applications i get this error:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl (in unnamed module @0x11da9ea1) cannot access class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64 (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util to unnamed module @0x11da9ea1
at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl.run(TomcatManagerImpl.java:533)

From what i can understand(speaking under correction) is that there is a compatibility issue so here is a screenshot of my system variables:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Swing button colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420311/java-swing-button-colors) I found your question while answering that question.