# java falling matrix code (like the movie)

Tags: java, graphics

If you wanted to write a program in java that uses a JFrame to simulate the falling green code from the matrix movie using ascii string characters so it looks exactly like this php example

http://mgccl.com/2007/03/30/simple-version-matrix-like-animated-dropping-character-effect-in-php

what would be the best way of doing it? labels, drawString? etc...

I know that within a for-loop for example you could use the integer value i to decrease the y-axis values, darken the color setColor(new Color(255, 255 - (i * 5), 255));

but i don't know how you would leave the "imprint" behind.

thanks

Comment: +1 for Imagination.Keep it up bro.

Answer (score 2):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234020) shows how to fade text using alpha transparency, while this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124507) illustrates how to fade text by varying the color saturation.

Addendum:

> What would be the best gui layout to use?

I'd solve the problem in a single, columnar `JPanel` that is as wide as the chosen `Font` and arbitrarily tall. Use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to control animation. Then use a [`new GridLaylout(1, 0)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) to contain any number of such columns as a single row.

Comment: so would jtextarea or paint(graphics g) be better to use overall?

Comment: I'd override the `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach 0 for i, you just start doing to same for two other channels so it will gradually turn black or disappear.

```
setColor(new Color(255 - (i * 5), 0, 255 - (i * 5)));
```

The length depends on the step size (which is 5 in your case and thus the length of the imprint is 51). So if you want short imprint, you have to do `numSteps = 255 / length` of the imprint (rounding issue should not be ignored):

```
i = numSteps..0
setColor(new Color(255 - (i * step), 0, 255 - (i * step)));
```

Comment: but what would be the best gui layout to use?

Comment: Not an expert in this regard. JTextArea has setSelectionStart, setSelectionEnd and setSelectionColor. So if you mimic the same approach (2D array of chars), you may achieve exactly the same effect. But how fast these methods are, I don't know.

Comment: Also if JAreaText requires server-client communication, that approach won't work at all. And I don't see any approach when something is generated on the server side working.

Comment: server side? i'm not looking to host it just to make it

Comment: I mean, something has to execute the code. If it's executed on the client, it's one thing. However if it is executed on the server and then rendering results are sent back to the client, it's very different