# Fading Jpanels in and out in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, fade

I would like to make a game with multiple JPanels in a single global JFrame. I would like to switch these JPanels but with a nice animation like fade in and fade out. How would you be able to fade a JPanel out, switch the JPanel to a new one, and fade the new in (preferably without an external library)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe  http://filthyrichclients.org/
has some nice ideas and **examples**(online) to get started. It contains many swing animation details.

Answer (score 2):

Could possibly do something like this on the panel and components to make them fade out:

```
Color bgColor = getBackground();

for(int alpha = bgColor.getAlpha(); alpha > = 0; alpha--)
{
    setBackground(new Color(
    bgColor.getRed(),
    bgColor.getGreen(),
    bgColor.getBlue(),
    alpha));
}
```

You will probably need to throw a Thread.sleep() in there.

Also have a look at:

```
com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this,opacity );
```

But note that this does the entire application

Comment: I Imagine it can be done by creating an BufferedImage of your JPanel and then displaying the image and fading it out.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, [`FlashTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything/2124507#2124507) shows how to fade by changing a color's saturation, while [`AlphaTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228735/how-do-i-fade-an-image-in-swing/2234020#2234020) shows how to fade by changing a color's alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a dummy javafx node, setting an animation for it, and binding the opacity property of the dummy node with your swing item.
it would be something like this

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.util.Duration;    
import javax.swing.*;

class transitions
{
    Button fade_reference = new Button();
    transitions.fade fade_transistion;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    transitions()
    {
        fade_transistion = new fade(fade_reference, 250, 0.2, 0.9);
        fade_reference.opacityProperty().addListener(observable-> {
            frame.setOpacity((float)fade_reference.getOpacity());
        });
    }

    class fade
    {
        private final Timeline show_timeline, hide_timeline;
        Node node;
        double min_opacity;
        double max_opacity;
        int annimation_duration;

        fade(Node node, int annimation_duration, double min_opacity, double max_opacity)
        {
            this.min_opacity = min_opacity;
            this.max_opacity = max_opacity;
            this.node = node;
            this.annimation_duration = annimation_duration;
            show_timeline = setupShowTransition();
            hide_timeline = setupDismissTransition();

        }

        private Timeline setupShowTransition()
        {
            return create_timeline(max_opacity);
        }

        private Timeline setupDismissTransition()
        {
            return create_timeline(min_opacity);
        }

        private Timeline create_timeline(double target_opacity)
        {
            Timeline tl = new Timeline();

            KeyValue kv1 = new KeyValue(node.opacityProperty(), node.getOpacity());
            KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kv1);

            KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(node.opacityProperty(), target_opacity);
            KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(annimation_duration), kv2);

            tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf1, kf2);
            return tl;
        }

        void fade_up()
        {
            show_timeline.play();
        }

        void fade_down()
        {
            hide_timeline.play();
        }
    }
}
```