# drawing layers using java graphics API

Tags: java, swing, graphics, layer, graphics2d

I'm doing a simulator project that tests several A* based algorithms and show how they work and their results.
The algorithms are all multi-agent and run on a grid map environment.

I used a JPanel for the grid which contains a two dimensional array of Cells where each Cell is a custom class that extends the Component class and use the paint method to draw the stuff i need inside each cell.
For the drawing inside the cell I use method such as Graphics.fillRect or Graphics.drawImage to fill each cell with a certain color or icon).

I'm using a special Icon for the start position and goal position of every agent on the grid.
My problem is that I want to be able to draw more than one item on the same cell.

For example I want to be able to show the path of one of the agents by painting the cells along the path in a special color and the path might go through a start position of a different agent, so I want to be able to fill the cell with the color and have an icon drawn on top.
In another example I want to be able to mix two colors using alpha blending.

If I use graphics.fillRect() with one color that has alpha and then use it again with a different color with alpha value it won't work since the last fillRect() will override the first call.

Is there a way I can achieve what I need using the same Cell Component I created or should I implement it differently?
Perhaps there is a better solution to this problem?
I would really appreciate any advice on this matter.

Comment: A deeper understanding of [alpha composite](http://keithp.com/~keithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf) may help. Also, people will take your questions more seriously if you accept and/or up-vote useful answers.

Comment: done, and I understand alpha compositing, but it doesn't solve the issue. If you draw a rectangle with 50% alpha and then draw another one the second one will override it instead of blending it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you draw a rectangle with 50% alpha and then draw another one, the second one will override it instead of blending with it.

It depends on the mode. This convenient [utility](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) shows the result of blending different colors using the modes defined in [`AlphaComposite`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html). The available [source code](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite/source-code) may offer some insights for your project.

Addendum:

> the stuff I was trying to composite was on the same `Component`.

The [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) [cited](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite/source-code) does exactly this, as does this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228735/how-do-i-fade-an-image-in-swing/2234020#2234020). If [`AlphaComposite`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) does not meet your requirements, you can always vary hue, saturation and/or value; this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything/2124507#2124507) composes a color table based on saturation.

Comment: I tried working with the alphaComposite object, but it didn't help much since the stuff I was trying to composite were on the same Component

Comment: thanks, I'll try looking at the example and see what i can make of it