# How to not paint a specific color with Swing/AWT?

Tags: java, swing, colors

I'm trying to use a sprite sheet in my game and I want the background to be transparent, how can I implement this using swing and/or awt?

Comment: Is the sprite sheet BG transparent now?

Answer (score 2):

have look at

1. [JLayer (Java7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) based on JXLayer (Java6)
2. [Translucency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)
3. Set transparency by using [`AlphaComposite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to create your sheets using a format that already supports transparency for background, like PNG 32bits.

Translucency and transparency options can only change the whole transparent channel of your image, not act on individual bits based on their colors.

Comment: `LookupOp`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383798/230513) may be used to alter an existing background color.

Comment: It makes a useful complement to `AlphaComposite`, suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384425/230513) and mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12392808/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on mKorbel's suggestion to use [`AlphaComposite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html), you *cannot* paint with `AlphaComposite.Clear` mode, but you *can* clear the background of a `BufferedImage`. For example,

```
Graphics2D dstG = dstImage.createGraphics();
dstG.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
dstG.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Subsequent painting in a different mode will leave unpainted pixels transparent.

More details may be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124035/230513).