# How to use lights in jcomponents?

Tags: java, swing, xaml, windows-7

Is it possible to add lights to jcomponents...? especially as an action on the jcomponent.

I mean something beyond changing background color of the component for example a jbutton...
I mean something like what we see in windows 7 components or actions done in xaml...

Comment: A screenshot would be nice. I have no idea what the windows 7 components done in xaml look like.

Answer (score 1):

You might get some ideas from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123841/javax-swing-timer-repeats-fine-but-actionlistener-doesnt-do-anything/2124507#2124507) using varied saturation or this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228735/how-do-i-fade-an-image-in-swing/2234020#2234020) using alpha. A slowly changing [`GradientPaint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html) might be useful, too.